User Switching and Logout Issues in a SAML-Authenticated Application with Keycloak
We have a JSF-based Enterprise Application (App_A) which uses another application (App_B) to authenticate and authorise users before accessing the application (App A).
App_B uses Keycloak to authenticate and authorisize users before accessing App_A
The authorisation mechanism is role-based, and all users are assigned different user groups based on the allowed services for a user group.
We have the following problematic scenarios.

Subsequently logging in as User in a different User Group

a) User logs out of App_A, logs in as a another user group via App_B and opens App_A as the new User: App_A still shows the previous user who just logged out
b) The new User switches to App_B and opens App_A again: Now App_A shows the correctly newly authenticated User

User logs out from App_B: Instead of the process displaying the login form of App_A, App_B is displayed again after a few seconds. Infact this is our main headache at the moment.

In all scenarios, apparently Keycloak still keep sessions when a user logs out of App_A. We have tried different approaches like removing cookies and cleaning headers, but not successful.
Our analysis has it that:

The Principal is not removed and thus assigned to the newly created session when he logs in as another User. The SAML credentials are maintained in the Principal
The logout process works, if the User logs out two times, that is, when App_A is displayed after the first log out, and the User logs out again, the login form of App B is displayed as expected.

There is a Logout Button for the for the logging out.
A workaround, which seems to work is to create a temporary tab that executes the first logout request and gets closed before authenticating as a new user, but this solution is not acceptable.
These are the feaures of the main App_A:
Wildfly - 24.0.1.Final
JakartaEE - 8.0.0
Primefaces - 13.0.8
Primefaces.all-themes - 1.0.10

We use SAML2 for the authentication via Keycloak, Version 23

We would be glad to have any solution directives.
Thank you
We tried different workarounds like deleting session cookies and header option on logout.

When you logout from any of the two applications, are you also calling the end_session_endpoint ok KeyCloak? It seems that, in the authorization process, users are redirect from App_A or App_B on KC, that still has an active (logged) session on it, and this is then returned to the main applications as a valid login.
